# The code execution cannot proceed because MSVCP100D.dll was not found

Tags: c++, visual-c++, exe

I was given an application called "program" by my teacher at my university. I can open the program at my university computer but somehow, i can't open it in my laptop. I try to look up some the solution like installing Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017 but still the program can't run.

Thanks for your time
[image]

Comment: Looks like an old binary. Probably need VS redis 2010

Comment: The "D" in msvcp100d.dll means "Debug".  You only get the debug versions of these DLL from a VS install.  You could build the Release configuration instead, but it is rather important that you consider copying source code instead of executable files to do your homework.

Answer (score 0):

Just tell him to give you the "release version" of the program.

Or you can download and install "visual studio 2010 express" for trial version to open the program.